# Arduino: Better way to monitor variables than Serial.print()?

Tags: arduino

When I test my code, I add Serial.print messages temporarily, to see what my code does. This is quite tedious, because there's no such thing as printf() in the Arduino world. Plus sometimes I forget to remove the Serial.print()s and I must search them later in my code to remove them. And if I put the Serial.print()s into a loop, the output will scroll so fast that I can't really track how the values are changing. Then I need delay(), which are yet another piece of test code to remove later.
Is there any library or tool out there that makes this task easier?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Visual Studio you can use VisualMicro for real debugging including breakpoints and value monitoring:
http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Debugging-for-Arduino.aspx

It works with the community edition of Visual Studio (which is free):
http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

I've used VisualMicro a lot and it's a real time saver because you can really focus on debugging and not on adding log calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tried and true conditional compilation method such as with:

```
#ifdef DEBUGGING
    Serial.print (something);
    Serial.print (somethingElse);
    delay (1000);
#endif
```

Then, compile yor test code with the `DEBUGGING` flag set, whilst leaving it off in the production code.

That way, you don't need to remove the debug code from your source, it's removed automatically by the compiler itself.

Comment: that's a good idea but keep in mind that using serial prints can change the behaviour of the code and add or remove bugs you won't have without the prints. Been there...

Comment: Well, yes, but then they're generally Heisenbugs in which case a debugger can also do that, as can running your code on the third Wednesday of the month :-)

Comment: ahah! did not know the name Heisenbugs, I like it! :)